# crear un create, read, update, delite en tiempo real con php y javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy creando un crud de usuarios con php y normalmente lo se crear creando las etiquetas html y con un for in hacer el recorrido de estos, pero quiero hacer esto en tiempo real, que con javascript hacer la consulta a el archivo php y de hay devolver los usuario pero no se me ocurre como almacenar estos para enviarlos para en un fetch

Comment: Hola Luis, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Answer (score 1):

se podría decir que quieres actualizar tu vista cada vez que alguien se registre, ¿cierto?, si es así, se me ocurren dos formas de hacerlo.

**1. Realizando peticiones al servidor con setIntervals.**

por medio de un setInterval podrías realizar peticiones a tu servidor para comprobar si la BD tiene nuevos registros y actualizar tu lista de usuarios.

```javascript
//algo tal que así:

setInterval(() =>{
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "rutadetuarchivo/Tu_archivo.php", true);

    xhr.onload = ()=>{
      if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
          if(xhr.status === 200){
            //lo que buscas realizar en tu archivo
          }
      }
    }

}, 500);
```

La desventaja de esto es que el proceso va a consumir la memoria del dispositivo en el que abras la página.

**2. Implementando WebSockets (sugiero esta última).**

Debido a que se usa puerto en el que se crea una comunicación entre el cliente y el servidor, la transferencia de la información se realiza casi en automático y no consume tantos recursos como la anterior solución, siempre y cuando tengas uno.

Fragmento de sobre cómo crear un servidor websocket:

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost'; //Tu host
$port = '9000'; //Puerto
$null = NULL; //null var

//Create TCP/IP sream socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
//reuseable port
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

...
```

script en JavaScript para asociar con tu servidor

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    //creacion de objeto Websocket.
    var wsUri = "ws://tuHost:9000/demo/server.php";     
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); 
    
    // mensaje desde el servidor
    websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
        var response = JSON.parse(ev.data); //Json del servidor
        
        var res_type = response.type; //datos del nuevo usuario registrado traido del servidor
         
    };

    
    
    //Se podria desencadenar al oprimir un boton de "Registrarse" el llenar el formulario de registro, por ejemplo:

    function send(){
        var name_input = $('#idDelInputDeNombre').val(); //nombre de usuario
        //demás datos
        
        //creacion de Json para el servidor 
        var msg = {
            nombre: name_input,
            //demás datos
        };
        //envio del mensaje al servidor
        websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));    
    }
</script>
```

Te dejo enlace de la [aplicación web en tiempo real](https://github.com/sanwebe/Chat-Using-WebSocket-and-PHP-Socket) de donde obtuve la referencia de los Websokets, en el podrás ver el código completo para que puedas guiarte :D.